# Embed zxing barcode scanner to the activity

Tags: android, embed, zxing

I'm writing android application and my client requires a barcode scanner in it. They are really specific about it, so the layout they want is like this:

[image]

If a qr code found - it jumps to another window automatically. If manual pressed - you are asked to type manually and proceed with the rest of the app.

So basically I could embed zxing code to my app and add it to the activity but I don't want that and would like to have it as a separate app.

What I have at the moment is a separate activity called like this:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

I also tried this:

```
IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
Intent i = intentIntegrator.initiateCustomScan();

LocalActivityManager mgr = getLocalActivityManager();

Window w = mgr.startActivity("unique_per_activity_string", i);
View wd = w != null ? w.getDecorView() : null;

if(wd != null) {
  scanButton.addView(wd);
}
```

But then I get java.lang.SecurityException:

```
03-19 12:22:55.890: E/AndroidRuntime(29394): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.menucard.barcode.scan/com.barcode.scan.ScanActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Requesting code from com.google.zxing.client.android (with uid 10139) to be run in process com.menucard.barcode.scan (with uid 10169)
```

Maybe someone has an idea how to add a separate app into my activity? Or other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: Since zxing is open source you can use their code and create your own view... why do you want to use their existing app?

Comment: First of all they don't recommend it themselves and I understand why. In this way I would only focus on having the link to their app, not the whole app.
If they update something, I also get the newest updates (of course if users decide to update barcode scanner app).

Comment: If you need to customize the scanning screen then I think using their code and creating your own layout would be a good idea since you can not change  the view of other apps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't embed an external app in another app via `Intent` unfortunately. The external app here needs to take over the whole screen, and is in landscape mode, for starters.

You should write your own app, but can reuse parts of Barcode Scanner in your app so that it's not entirely from scratch. Just please don't copy the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. I think it will also be clearly not confused with Barcode Scanner given the different UI. All that remains is to make sure you follow the terms of the Apache License (easy).

Comment: +1 Yes I have thought of writing own scanning app, can you guide me on which particular folder of files I should refer to? is it the CaptureActivity.java? So far I have managed to port the entire source into my project, this is just for learning purposes, I did not intent to copy, as I'm totally new to android development.

Comment: I can't encourage you to start by copying the app. Start by writing your own app with everything but the scanning. Until you have that level of knowledge you won't know how to use the Barcode Scanner source anyway.

Answer (score 1):

@MindaugasSvirskas, your last comment is exactly what I was about to post now:-) I have faced the same problem in the past, in several apps, and believe me, just make use of Intents, that's the way the whole Android system is designed, favouring intercommunication between apps. iOS programmers can easily integrate the scanning Zxing layout in their own layouts, but we are supposed to make use of intents, and I agree.